# JQuery-UI datepicker bugs out when I hack the "today" button to also select the date but only in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery-ui-datepicker

I've used various "fixes" to make the today button also select the date and so far all of them worked nicely on Firefox but IE bugs out when I use them. Whenever I click today, the date gets selected, the input field updated and the datepicker closed but IE imediately opens another datepicker that can't be closed unless you open a new datepicker.

This is the datepicker code with the fixes I used

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();            
            $j('#data1, #data2').datepicker({ dayNames: ['Duminica', 'Luni', 'Marti', 'Miercuri', 'Joi', 'Vineri', 'Sambata'], dayNamesMin: ['Du', 'Lu', 'Ma', 'Mi', 'Jo', 'Vi', 'Sa'], firstDay: 1,
                monthNames: ['Ianuarie','Februarie','Martie','Aprilie','Mai','Iunie','Iulie','August','Septembrie','Octombrie','Noiembrie','Decembrie'], 
                monthNamesShort: ['Ian','Feb','Mar','Apr','Mai','Iun','Iul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Noi','Dec'],
                showOtherMonths: true,
                selectOtherMonths: true,            
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                defaultDate: new Date(),
                changeMonth: true,
                showButtonPanel: true, currentText: 'Astazi',
                changeYear: true    
            });
```

The first fix I used:

```
$j('button.ui-datepicker-current').live('click', function() {
$j.datepicker._curInst.input.datepicker('setDate', new Date()).datepicker('hide');
});
```

just after I initialize the datepicker.

Also rewrote the function with

```
var _gotoToday = jQuery.datepicker._gotoToday;
// datepicker is directly inside the jQuery object, so override that
jQuery.datepicker._gotoToday = function(a){
var target = jQuery(a);
var inst = this._getInst(target[0]);
// call the old function, so default behaviour is kept
_gotoToday.call(this, a);
// now do an additional call to _selectDate which will set the date and close
// close the datepicker (if it is not inline)
jQuery.datepicker._selectDate(a, 
jQuery.datepicker._formatDate(inst,inst.selectedDay, inst.selectedMonth,  inst.selectedYear));
}
```

Also tried just adding

```
this._setDateDatepicker(target, new Date());
this._selectDate(id, this._getDateDatepicker(target));
```

at the end of the _gotoToday function

All of them did exactly what you'd expect in firefox but left me with the issue I mentioned above when used with IE.

Answer (score 2):

For me, this one works, also in IE:

```
jQuery.datepicker._gotoToday = function(id) {
    var today = new Date();
    var dateRef = jQuery("<td><a>" + today.getDate() + "</a></td>");
    this._selectDay(id, today.getMonth(), today.getFullYear(), dateRef);
};
```